# Why I'm getting "Runtime error <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: Object: CreateObject Layer invalid data source" while adding shapefile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I am trying to add shapefile using ArcPy, but each time my script is ending in showing runtime error? I am using ArcGIS 10.

Here is my script

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

Master="G:\path\To\ShapeFile.shp"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(Master)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer,"BOTTOM")

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

This script works fine when I add .lyr files, but why it isn't working for .shp

Comment: What is your path to shapefile? Could it be something special in the path string? Try the same script with `C:\GIS\Simple.shp` to make sure it works with the simple path.

Comment: I assume you run the script in the ArcMap session? When I do with my shapefile, the code you've published works.

Comment: I am running it in ArcMap's python window, therefore, yes in the ArcMap session. Mine is ArcGIS 10. What version you're using? @AlexTereshenkov

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Master = r"G:\path\To\ShapeFile.lyr"
```

[arcpy.mapping.Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer.htm) only works with .lyr files acccording to Esri documentation but it seems to accept .shp files as well.

See here for info about  [raw strings](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer.htm)

Comment: I already tried this, it's also giving the same error.

Comment: The function  only accepts .lyr files.

Comment: What to do for .shp files?

Comment: Sorry, that script should  work with shapefiles....can you post the full error msg?

Comment: Question title itself shows the full error message, what I see on the ArcGIS python window.

Comment: Check your file path then for special characters. see @Alex Tereshenkov comments

Answer (score -1):

Problem with your path, so check that.

Change to `Master=r"G:\path\To\ShapeFile.shp"`